# Ms Access and Ora-00942 error

Tags: oracle, ms-access

I'm attempting to create a pass-through query (PTQ)in MS Access to my local Oracle XE instance via OBDC.  When I run my PTQ I get an Ora-00942 error "table or view doesn't exist".  I have ensured that the table does exist and the user I'm connecting as can Select data from the table using SQL-Plus.  The statement I'm using in the PTQ runs fine in Sql-Plus.

I have verified my connection string is correct by successfully running:

SELECT sysdate from dual;

If I try to link the table, I can browse to it and create the link. When I try to open it I get an Ora-00942 error again.

I'm thinking it is a security issue on the database side but I'm not certain.  I would appreciate any and all help.

===========================

A restart of the local Oracle service  resolved the issue.   Exact source is unknown but got it working.

Comment: If you run the pass-through query `SELECT USER FROM DUAL`, does it return the user you are expecting?